# Extend superclass in middle of class-herarchy in library

Tags: java, design-patterns, subclass, superclass

I'm using this library and I've had to override some methods in a few super-classes. What I do now is extending the class I need and re-define the methods I need to override from it's super-class.

```
class A { ... }

class B extends A { ... }

class C extends A { ... }

class myD extends B {

    protected void overriddenAfunction() { ... }

}
```

This obviously isn't good when several classes extends the same super-class and I want all the sub-classes to use the same overriden methods (like if C would also need the same definition of overridenAFunction()).

Is there some design pattern or way to make this pretty? I'm imagining you could do something like this:

```
class A { ... }

class B extends A { ... }

class C extends A { ... }

class myD extends A {

    private A BorC = null;

    public myD(A BorC) {

        this.BorC = BorC;

    }

    protected void overriddenAfunction() { ... }

    public void overriddenBfunction() { 

        ((B) BorC).overriddenBfunction();

    }

    public void overriddenCfunction() { 

        ((C) BorC).overriddenCfunction();

    }

}

Usage:

A testB = new myD(new B());
A testC = new myD(new C());
```

However then I'd need to put in every method from B and C if it even works.

Is there a better way or workaround? All I want to do is avoid re-packaging the library though I guess it's really the best solution?

I guess I could also make copies of B and C and have them extend myD while myD extends A. This library also have all the source-files available so I can do this or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to override `A` in a way that lets `B` and `C` benefit from the new functionality. You only have two options that I can see, and you mention them both:

- Rewrite `A` and repackage the library
- Let `MyD` extend `A`, and then Make copies of `B` and `C` that extend `MyD` instead.

Comment: I probably did a bad job of explaining the situation. I'm working with JFreeChart (it's a library for drawing charts). It've got one class NumberAxis (A) with functions controlling among other things how the ticks on the axes should be drawn. Then it've got the classes DateAxis (B) and SymbolAxis (C) that extend that class. Those classes contain some specific functions like settings the format of the labels. What I want to do is some efficient way of overriding the methods in NumberAxis so both DateAxis and SymbolAxis can use them.